# Min and Max values from one table and another value from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have few tables with some data in them.
And my task is to find highest and lowest observed temperature and where they were measured (With one query).

My tables :

location

```
| location_id | location_name |
| --------    | --------------|
| 1           | New York      |
| 2           | Chicago       |
| 3           | Los Angeles   |
| 4           | San Francisco |
```

observation

```
| observation_id | ref_location |temperature|
| --------       | ------------ | -----     |
| 1              | 1            |20.0       |
| 2              | 2            |18.0       |
| 3              | 3            |3.0        |
```

As you can see location_id and ref_location has to be linked between eachother

This is how my answer should look like.

```
if(!empty($result))
{
    echo "<table>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row['location_name']."</td>
                <td>".$row['temperature']."</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

At the moment my query looks like this:

```
SELECT MIN(observation.temperature) AS temperature,
        MAX(observation.temperature) AS temperature, 
        location_name AS location_name 
FROM observation 
    INNER JOIN location ON observation.ref_location=location.location_id;
```

Comment: _Small Point_ 2 aliases with the same name isnt going to make life easy :) `temperature`

Comment: The problem you're going to run up against is being able to get the matching ID with the min() or max() temperature.  The way around it is to use `row number over partion by`.  If this is a school assignment for you, I'll leave it at that for you to do the research.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is getting the temperature max and min id and use it in the where condition
Try:

```
SELECT location_name,temperature
FROM observation o
INNER JOIN location l ON o.ref_location=l.location_id
WHERE temperature IN (
                         SELECT MIN(temperature) from observation
                         union
                         SELECT MAX(temperature) from observation
                     ) ;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vwi9bkdUVPoZeURdNAEoDX/7

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. Thank you for the answers

```
(SELECT ref_location, MIN(temperature) AS temperature, location_id, location_name
              FROM observation, location
              WHERE location_id=ref_location
              GROUP BY temperature, ref_location ORDER BY temperature LIMIT 1)
              UNION
              (SELECT ref_location, MAX(temperature) AS temperature, location_id, location_name
              FROM observation, location
              WHERE location_id=ref_location
              GROUP BY temperature, ref_location ORDER BY temperature DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what your code does.